# If i have 42 tera hashes of mining power, how long will it take me to mine a block solo, and if i join a mining pool, how much bitcoin will I get?

Tags: hash

If i have 42 tera hashes of mining power, how long will it take me to mine a block solo, and if i join a mining pool, how much bitcoin will I get? I am intrested in buying 4 Bitmain Antminer T9+.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, less power costs, and assuming no change in difficulty:

- it would take on average 50 years, 21 weeks to generate a block.
- it would produce on average 0.000678 BTC per day, or about $6.70.

Comment: Can you explain how you reached these values? Currently it looks like numbers pulled out of thin air.